# Unexpected error -> "AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'xaxis'"

Tags: python, matplotlib

I don't know what's wrong, it worked in a similar project. Any ideas?

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib import ticker
    import pandas as pd

    df1 = (...)
    df2 = (...)


    ax, fig = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,10))
    fig.plot(df1["x"], df1["y"], marker = "o", linestyle = 'None' , markeredgecolor = "black" )
    fig.plot(df2["x"], df2["y"], marker = "o", linestyle = 'None' , markeredgecolor = "red" )
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.NullLocator()) #Error line
    ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.NullLocator())
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.NullFormatter())
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.NullFormatter())

    plt.show()
```

Out:
AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'xaxis'

Comment: It should be `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` and `ax.plot()` because this is what is returned by [`plt.subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) - a figure artist `fig` and an (array of) axis object(s) `ax`. I suggest [reading the tutorials](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-introductory-usage-py) to understand the difference between figures and axis objects.